# get long from bytearray of 4 bytes in android

Tags: android

I am working on android and trying to read tcp socket , my tcp server is sending array of bytes which is created from array of long .

In my android code i am able to read array of bytes but unable to got long values from this array .

My code is as below .

```html
while (true)
                        {
                            if(isClosed){break;}
                            message = "";
                            //byte[] buffer=new byte[4];
                            if (socket != null)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    int bytesRead;
                                    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                                    byte[] data = new byte[44];
                                    while ((bytesRead=inputStream.read()) != -1)
                                    {
                                        int count = inputStream.read(data);
                                        bytearraytolong(data);
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.i("ThreadTask","readFromStream: "+ e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.i("ThreadTask", "SocketConnection : Cannot Read, Socket is closed");
                            }
                        }
```

```html
private void bytearraytolong(byte[] bf)
{
    // how to get long here
}
```

here my tcp server sending data of 44 bytes so it have 11 long type values ,

i want to back orignal value in my android application "bytearraytolong" method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looking at ByteBuffer (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

You might also want to check to make sure the server is serializing the type consistently with how you are deserializing; the byte order can vary in some cases.

Also, if your server is only sending 44 bytes, then you probably are dealing with ints, not longs.  Longs are 8 bytes.

The snippet of code you are looking for would be

```
private Long readLongFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
  return bb.getLong();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but Long is 8 bytes as per @Clayton Wilkinson said.

```
public static long decodeLong(byte[] input) {
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (i >= 8) {
            break;
        }
        result += ((long) input[i] & 0xff) << ((input.length - i - 1) * 8);
    }

    return result;
}
```